# add char infront of each word in string with java

Tags: java, replace, string-matching

im trying to take a string and add + infront of each word in a string to auto generate keywords

so if the string was: Green sheep

the output should be: +Green +sheep

Comment: `String.replaceAll` should help you.

Comment: @Flown replaceAll will not work for 1st word

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("\\b(\\pL)", "+$1");` (replace word boundary followed by letter).

Comment: Unfortunately your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We first extract all words, then manipulate them and finally put them back as sentence.

```
// Extract words
String[] words = theString.split(" ");

// Manipulate them
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    words[i] = "+" + words[i];
}

// Put them back as sentence
StringJoiner sj = new StringJoiner(" ");
for (String word : words) {
    sj.add(word);
}

String sentence = sj.toString();
```

The `StringJoiner` adds a `" "` between every argument (specified in the constructor).

Note that this approach only works for *simple sentences* where every word is split by a *space* and not *commas*, *dots*, and so on.

Comment: Why go through all that when a single `replaceAll()` [can do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447392/add-char-infront-of-each-word-in-string-with-java#comment79850846_46447392)?

Comment: Complex code for simple solution.

Comment: Yeah but it is indeed helpful for beginners to understand how this can be done in detail.

Comment: @Zabuza start reading any book of Introduction To Java. Purpose of SO is different. :-)

Comment: ok more effective solution would be theString.replaceAll()

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple options, I will focus on a compact **regex** answer that uses `\b` which matches all word boundaries, even complex ones like in `Green, sheep. Green - sheep`.

### Solution

```
String text = "Green, sheep. Green - sheep";
String modifiedText = text.replaceAll("\\b(\\p{L}+)\\b", "+$1");
System.out.println(modifiedText);
```

Which outputs:

```
+Green, +sheep. +Green - +sheep
```

**<kbd>[JDoodle Demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/a/8t5)</kbd>**

### Explanation

A detailled explanation can be seen at [regex101#K4k42n](https://regex101.com/r/K4k42n/4). One of many good sites to test **regex**.

In short we search for words `\\p{L}` (only letter characters), multiple of it `+`, inside word boundaries `\\b`. Those words are then put into a capturing group with `(...)`. In the second argument of `replaceAll` we can now refer to capturing groups with `$`, `$1` corresponds to the match of the first capturing group and so on.

So we substitute a word by the symbol `+` together with the word itself `$1`.

Comment: The downside about regex is that no one understands what is happening. Sure it's handy, but it's a double edged sword.

Comment: Indeed. It is a very handy tool for novice programmers. For beginners I would suggest a very straightforward manual way like @ihsankocak showed in his answer. The nice thing is that `\b` from regex is very powerful, will be hard to detect complex boundaries manually.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:
1. Split the string on the basis of spaces.
2. Iterate in a loop.
3. Get a single string and add "+" infront, space afterward and add the string to final string
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 till the end of list obtained in step 1.

Its always better to post logic/pseudo-codes instead of posting a code.
Hope this will help you. :-)

Comment: Why go through all that when a single `replaceAll()` [can do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447392/add-char-infront-of-each-word-in-string-with-java#comment79850846_46447392)?

Comment: replaceAll will not work for 1st word because 1st word does not contains space

Comment: You're wrong. The comment I linked in the previous comment showed a regex for `replaceAll()` that works even for first word. So does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46447804/5221149).

Comment: In my opinion it is best to post both, the logic **and** the code.

Comment: @Andreas, I read you have written String.replaceAll() method only. Missed your "can do it" link due to my faded screen color. :-P

Comment: @Andreas, OP is only a beginner and instead of complex regex patterns, we can help him/her to understand, the way to start things better. Hope u agree. :-) I can also post some complex regex patterns but what is the point if OP did not get what is happening inside "//b+*()//" :-P

Comment: @Zabuza, because posting code is more easier than explaining logic and/or writing pseudo-codes :-P

Comment: @Aman I share the same opinion with you when it comes to *'logic helps beginners far more than code'* but I think it is best to pair the logic with some easy straightforward code. Beginners may have problems transposing clear logic in some code, because they do not have the experience yet. I think we can both agree on that :)